# Regex in htaccess is just passing 1 character

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I did use a regex in htaccess to match a twitter-like username in my website but its just passing to the php file the last char to the $_GET['referer'] var.

This is the regular expression: **^(\w){1,15}$**

For example, if i go to signup/johndoe/ it will send to php the "e"

Here is my htaccess, as you may see, i'm not a apache server expert. Love 4 u all, happy new year.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^signup/(\w){5,15}/?$ signup.php?referer=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the parentheses. Instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/(\w){5,15}/?$ signup.php?referer=$1
```

You want:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/(\w{5,15})/?$ signup.php?referer=$1
```

So that it returns the entire set of matched characters, instead of just the last one.